# Why does Excel only invoke the Text Import Wizard for .txt files?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, microsoft-excel-2013, textfiles

Excel ignores comma delimiters in .csv files, but invokes the Text Import Wizard for .txt files that "appear delimited". Surely it should behave the same way for .csv files?

Comment: For me, I use [a small PowerShell tool](http://superuser.com/a/527894/50173) which I assigned to the extension CSV. The tool opens Excel and tells it to use the text import wizard to import the currently selected CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always compel the Wizard to appear.

**First** open Excel, then, using the Ribbon, goto the *Data* tab and then touch *From Text* in the *Get External Data* group.

If you do not need the Wizard, then simply double-click the file's icon to open it.