# How to Avoid rounding off when converting from CSV to Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

As far as I know (") double quotes are used in the CSV file and who opening the file in Excel it should treat that as Text and all the numbers should displayed.

My actual CSV file value is: 1,026.549400
After converting to Excel it is : 1,026.55
I used double quotes in the program to get the commas in the value but I need to exact decimal values as this is critical data in the report.
As the CSV file is transmitting to our client is there any chance to do this in CSV file without any manual work on Excel side.Can someone suggests me on this?

Comment: Have you checked the cell formatting?

Comment: @Burgi - Thanks for your reply .Cells are in **General** Format and probably it will work if we change the format of the cell to TEXT but this gives the manual effort here which is not preferrable.

Comment: Can you provide a quick sample of the data you are importing?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/307496/how-can-i-set-excel-to-always-import-all-columns-of-csv-files-as-text