# Set Excel Workbook Name using PowerShell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, powershell

In regard to nixda's answer in [How can I set Excel to always import all columns of CSV files as Text?](https://superuser.com/questions/307496/how-can-i-set-excel-to-always-import-all-columns-of-csv-files-as-text), how can I set the workbook name in PS when I am using this script (PowerShell script to open CSVs directly from Windows Explorer) to open a text or csv file? Using the script provided by nixda, the workbook name is book1 (the default).

I can't seem to find a good reference that discusses workbook naming in PowerShell.

Comment: I was hoping for a workbook.name function to set it without saving it so I can use the linked ps script to import text and use an existing macro on the open file. If I open the file in excel directly it retains the name of the file, using the linked ps script it gets changed to book1. I guess I Should be been more specific about that. I will check the link you sent (I may have installed it already in my travails looking for answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I have clearly misunderstood your question. You want to change workbook name. I think that workbook name is set when saved. You can use ComObjects `SaveAs()` method:

```
$workbook.SaveAs("C:\Users\user\Desktop\TEST.xlsx")
```

---

<s>By inspecting Excel.Application com object which was used in mentioned answer, it seems you can set the Excel sheet name with following code:</s>

```
$excel = new-object -ComObject excel.application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$workbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "TEST"
```

When you check it by changing Visible property from false to true:

```
$excel.Visible = $true
```

Name should change.

---

Additionaly, you can check Doug Finke's `ImportExcel` Powershell module, it provides very nice way of manipulating excel files (only new xlsx format)

https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel