# How to get folder location of file? (Powershell)

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, csv

I am using the script below, found on [this thread.](https://superuser.com/questions/307496/how-can-i-set-excel-to-always-import-all-columns-of-csv-files-as-text).  I would like to automatically save the Excel file in the same folder as the CSV file, using the same name as the CSV file.

How can I get the folder location and filename?

```
$CSVs = @()
$args.ForEach({
    If ((Test-Path $_) -and ($_ -Match "\.csv$|\.txt$")) {
        $CSVs += ,$_
    } 
})

if (-Not $null -eq $CSVs) {

    $excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
    $excel.visible = $true
    $excel.SheetsInNewWorkbook = $CSVs.Count    
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()

    for ($i=0; $i -lt $CSVs.Count; $i++){

        $csv = Get-Item $CSVs[$i]
        $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item($i + 1)
        $worksheet.Name = $csv.basename

        $TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $csv.fullname)
        $Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$worksheet.Range("A1"))
        $query = $worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name)
        $query.TextFilePlatform = 65001
        $query.TextFileTextQualifier = 1
        $query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $Excel.Application.International(5) 
        $query.TextFileParseType  = 1
        $arrFormats = ,2 * $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count
        $query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = $arrFormats
        $query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1
        $query.Refresh()
        $query.Delete()
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

It/they would be in $args. $args will only be populated if the script is launched from the SendTo shortcut created in your linked post.

```
$args | ForEach{
  echo ('Path: "{0}"' -f (Split-Path $_))
  echo ('FIle: "{0}"' -f (Split-Path $_ -Leaf))
}
```

Comment: Is different type of variables, why not use Resolve-Path $_ ?

Comment: Because with paths being passed from **Explorer** (this is a context menu script), there are no wildcards to resolve.

Comment: Thank you for explanation...

Comment: You're welcome. It's not clear where the arguments are coming from until you check out the linked thread.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen after your last comment about context menu/explorer