# Is there a way to sort digits within a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'd like to know if there's an Excel Function, or a formula, that can be used to sort digits within a cell.

For example, if the value of A1 is `6193254807` and B1 has our formula with parameters set to sort ascending then B1 should equal `0123456789` (leading zero included).  Of course, if the parameters were set so that it would sort descending then B1 should equal `9876543210`.

Is there a way to do this, without wandering into VBScript, or macros, or something similarly exotic?

Comment: do you mean a single cell display the min or max for that column?

Comment: unfortunately leading zeroes will cause the numbers to be interpreted as text and thus textual sorting will happen, which is not what you will want

Comment: Is there any way to have Excel convert the numbers to text and back, as part of the formula?  I'm wanting to do mathematical operations on the resulting number.

Comment: I would think since 0123456789 will be interpreted as text if there is a leading zero, you might use a decimal point. What type of data is prepending the 0, or is it a data entry being made?

Comment: @datatoo I'm trying to have Excel do some mathematical acrobatics that require maintaining the same amount of digits within a number.  So, while the inputs may or may not have a leading zero, I need the outputs to retain any zeroes encountered even if they end up at the front.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with an array formula. Assuming the original number is in **A1**, enter any of the ff. into a blank cell and commit it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

***Ascending:***

```
=REPT(0,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,"")))&
 SUM(POWER(10,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,""))))-1)*
     LARGE(INT(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)),
            ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,""))))))
```

***Descending:***

```
=SUM(POWER(10,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,""))))-1)*
     SMALL(INT(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,""),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,"")))),1)),
           ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,""))))))
 &REPT(0,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,"")))
```

**Example:**

[image]

Each formula takes the *n* th largest or smallest number in the cell and multiplies it by a power of 10 according to its "rank" (a.k.a. assign it a new place value), which are then summed up to produce the "rearranged" number. For example, if our original number is `231` the general calculation steps for the first formula would be as follows:

```
=sum(1*power(10,2), 2*power(10,1), 3*power(10,0))  
=sum(100,20,3)
=123
```

The `REPT()` segment of the formula takes care of any leading or trailing zeros.

**The result will be in text format**. I figured this would be a good idea since there's a limit to how many digits you can enter in a cell (I recommend reading [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/437764/why-is-excel-truncating-my-16-digit-numbers)).

If you want to do some calculations with the result, just insert `0+` at the beginning of the formula to turn the result into a number.

Comment: this does look good, but I wonder what kinds of input generates leading zero numbers in the first place and how accurate calculations might be if the initial format is textual anyway, I get odd results with numbers ending in zeroes, they all seem to prepend to the number.

Comment: +1 please my ignorance in misreading the question completely. You are rightly sorting the content IN the cell.